# Throwing out embedded points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is an irreducible scheme, but maybe generically non-reduced or with embedded points.  Is there some natural scheme structure on $X$ that gets rid of the embedded points, but remembers the generic non-reduced structure?  What would such a thing be called?

One might try to do something like take the scheme-theoretic closure of the generic point, but I'm not sure whether this closure will contain the embedded points or not.